# adding receiver to manifest

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

In my android app I am able to call successfully a broadcast receiver class from mainactivity. I named it in the manifest like this

```
<receiver
            android:name="com.androidhive.pushnotifications.AlarmReceiver"
            android:process=":remote" />
```

It is working but when I define a broadcast receiver inside mainactivity as an inner class and named it in manifest as

```
<receiver
            android:name="com.androidhive.pushnotifications.AlarmReceiver1"
            android:process=":remote" />
```

it is not working .please give me the difference in adding a receiver class to manifest according to which whether it is inner class or an outside class.

Answer (score 0):

```
<receiver android:name="com.package.yourClass$AlarmReceiver1">
   android:process=":remote"
</receiver>
```

and your receiver have to be static!